# Python: Change a few characters at a certain location in a certain line of a file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, line, edit

I know there are many questions regarding editing lines of a file, but my problem is quite specific and in two days I couldn't find a question/answer here which hits it.

### The Problem

How do I replace a few (contiguous) characters **s1** of one specific line in a file with another few characters **s2** meeting the following conditions?

1. The line number is always the same. (number 5)
2. The part of the line in front of s1 is always the same. (and therefore has constant length = 18)
3. The part of the line in front of s1 won't occur anywhere else in the file.
4. s1 and s2 both are not constant and can even have different lengths.
5. s1 and s2 both may occur anywhere else in the file.
6. The file can be very long, so I don't want to load the whole file into memory.
7. For the same reason as 6. I want to avoid copying the file contents into a new file. Im just changing a few characters so rewriting the whole file would be much of a overhead, wouldn't it?
8. I'm using Python 3.X.

Most similar approaches I found so far didn't meet either 6. or 7. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25462054) (opening the file with `r+` and performing a `write(s2)` right before s1), but it doesn't work for me because of 4. Is it even possible in Python to achieve what I want or do I have to copy my file somehow and modify the line along the way after all?

### The Background

I have a text file consisting of a few lines of metadata followed by a potentially large number of datasets. The metadata contains a line saying `No. of patterns : n` while n is the number of datasets in the file. Among other things my script should be able to append additional datasets to an existing file by appending the sets themselves and updating n.
The design of this file I want to be generated/extended by my script is not invented by me, so I mustn't change it. The file will serve as input for another application not invented by me - the JavaNNS.

Comment: Use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) with `inplace=True`.

Comment: 6 is alleviated by iterating over the file `for line in file` because Python will naturally grab as you go instead of loading the whole thing at once. 7 I personally think you're exaggerating the overhead of writing to a new file, but if it's really that important you can always modify as you go by opening the file `r+`.

Comment: @PeterWood the Python docs say that it just backs it by moving it into a temp file and redirects stdout to your file. That still makes a copy

Comment: @Peter Wood: Well, well! So after all there was a possibility to arbitrarily edit a file in place! (At least formally.) I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist: Yeah, as for `for line in file` I thought so, too. By 6 and 7 I meant that normally one has to choose between either loading the whole file into memory or writing a new file. There are many examples for that out there. I just wanted to know if there was a possibility of doing none of the two. And yes, maybe I am exaggerating the overhead in 7, but it appeared to me so unsubtle to rewrite the whole file for 2 to 3 characters...

Comment: @S818 Doing neither of the two would be accomplished by iterating over the file `for line in file` and opening it in `r+` mode. =)

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist: Yes, that's right! In the end I did just that. (with additional `enumerate(file)`) The script works fine this way. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25462054) states

> you can only extend and truncate a file at the end, not at the head

With this limitation, python just mirrors the restrictions imposed by the data storage abstraction we call 'file system'. All programs, no matter the programming language, are bound by this when using the file system. Some just hide this fact from the user by re-writing complete files in the background.

If due to the size of the file this causes performance problems when updating the file, then that's really a problem of that crude file format, even though you aren't the one to be blamed for that: The file format doesn't seem to be suited for in-place updates of the file that change the number of patterns.

## How to avoid (re)writing large amounts of data

### Pipes

If the program which will consume the updated file (JavaNNS) accepts the file contents on standard input, consider to keep the meta-data and the patterns in separate files. Like this, you can append the patterns file and only have the re-write the (hopefully small) meta-data file. Then, just pipe both files into JavaNNS in a single call:

```sh
cat metadata.txt patterns.txt | JavaNNS
```

If JavaNNS does **not** take accept the required file content on standard input but insists on opening the file itself, you can probably still use a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) and pass that as the file to open. (This might not work if JavaNNS does random access on the file instead of just reading and seeking.)

### Padding

If you'll be appending to the file several times and the file format is flexible enough to allow some padding, then just pad to make some space for `n` with potentially increased number of digits in future writes. Like this, you only have to rewrite the file completely when the padding wasn't sufficiently large.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I understand now that there is no way to cheat the file system.
The pipes look very interesting. To split the files in two had also come to my mind, but I didn't think of pipes. Instead, I considered editing the first file via a combination of append and truncate and then joining both files again, but obviously this would violate 7 several times and there are better ways to write into a new file, for example in achampion's answer. But after all I don't think the pipe strategy will work with JavaNNS.

Comment: Fortunately JavaNNS doesn't mind leading zeros before or whitespace behind the number I want to change, so I will go with the padding approach. This is a bit dirty but genius at the same time! :-) And with this I achieve all my goals. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't edit in place and just change s1 for s2 as they can be different lengths. You will need to write out the rest of the file, and this will be safer with a replacement file.

If s1 and s2 are guaranteed to be the same length then you could do it in place, e.g. the value is padded to the maximum size of s1/s2:

```
with open('<file>', 'r+') as f:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
        if line_no == 5:      # read 5 lines
            f.seek(18, 1)     # jump forward 18 characters
            f.write("{: 8d}".format(s2))  # overwrite with padded s2 (int)
            break
```

With different lengths you will need a different file:

```
with open('<file>', 'r') as r:
    with open('<file-new>', 'w+') as w: 
        for line_no, line in enumerate(r):
            if line_no == 5:
                w.write(line[:18] + str(s2) + line[18+len(s1):])
            else:
                w.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Since I decided to use padding, your code piece comes in handy! The second one could be useful another time when padding won't work.